# Add WordPress filter to ACF WYSIWYG field

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wysiwyg

I am currently using the following filter to replace any instance of the string 'magic_click_link' within WordPress' `the_content`.

```
function click_link ($b) {
    global $post;
    $this_post_id = $post->ID;
    $op_name = get_field('operator_name');
    $namenospace = make_no_space("$op_name");

    $tracking_link = '/go/'.$this_post_id.'/';

    $click_link = '<a class="claimCTA" id="operator-step1-'.$namenospace.'" href="'.$tracking_link.'" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Click here to go to '.$op_name.'!</a>';

    $b = str_ireplace('magic_click_link',$click_link,$b);
    return $b;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'click_link');
```

I have just updated this field to use an ACF WYSIWYG field, but this has caused the filter to stop working.

I believe I need to target something other than `the_content` inside the filter but I'm not sure what is needed...

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but I did notice that you are not using `$go_page` as you set `$tracking_link` to use `/go/`.

Comment: sorry ignore those lines

Comment: How did you go with this @James?

Answer (score 2):

The filter `the_content` automatically runs on any content output using the function `the_content()`, so by default, this means it only applies to standard WordPress post and page content.

To apply these filters to your custom field content as well, you need to manually call `apply_filters()` when you output the field's content.

For example, say your custom field is called `my_extra_content`. With Advanced Custom Fields, you can call:

```
echo apply_filters("the_content", get_field("my_extra_content"));
```

This will output the content of your field, while applying all the usual filters against it. Because your `click_link()` function is hooked to `the_content` already, it will therefore process your custom field content as you are desiring.